# How do I compare random result against dictionary keys with 2 values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm just starting out in Python, and I'm trying to modify a simple rock paper scissors game to be rock paper scissors lizard spock. As a result I now need to compare a randomly generated computer choice against not 1, but 2 dictionary items which indicate loosing values:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import time

rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3
lizard = 4
spock = 5

names = { rock: "Rock", paper: "Paper", scissors: "Scissors", lizard: "Lizard", spock: "Spock"}
rules = { rock: [scissors, lizard], paper: [rock, spock], scissors: [paper, lizard], lizard: [paper, spock], spock: [rock, scissors]}

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

def start():
    print "Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock"
    while game():
        pass
    scores()

def game():
    player = move()
    computer = random.randint(1, 5)
    result (player, computer)
    return play_again()

def move():
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_input("Rock     = 1\nPaper    = 2\nScissors = 3\nLizard   = 4\nSpock    = 5\nMake a move: ")
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1,2,3,4,5):
                return player
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print "Oops! I didn't understand that. Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5."

def result(player, computer):
#   print "1..."
#   time.sleep(1)
#   print "2..."
#   time.sleep(1)
#   print "3!"
#   time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer])
    global player_score, computer_score
    for i in rules[player]:
        if i == computer:
            global outcome
            outcome = "win"
    if outcome == "win":
        print "Your victory has been assured."
        player_score += 1
    elif player == computer:
        print "Tie game."
    else:
        print "The computer laughs as you realise you have been defeated."
        computer_score += 1

def play_again():
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to play again? y/n: ")
    if answer in ("y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "Of course!"):
        return answer
    else:
        print "Thank you very much for playing. See you next time!"

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print "HIGH SCORES"
    print "Player: ", player_score
    print "Computer: ", computer_score

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

---

Unfortunately this code results in the player always winning... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `player` and `otherPlayer` hold the codes for the hand forms they made. Then you can check losing by checking if one players' code is contained in the losing conditions of the other player's code.

```
if player in rules [otherPlayer]: doSomething()
```

Without criticising your code, I personally would implement it somehow along these lines. Maybe you can grab an idea of two from it, or even some patterns, you surely won't want to use:

```
import random

rules = '''Scissors cut paper
Paper covers rock
Rock crushes lizard
Lizard poisons Spock
Spock smashes scissors
Scissors decapitate lizard
Lizard eats paper
Paper disproves Spock
Spock vaporizes rock
Rock crushes scissors'''

rules = rules.lower ().split ()
rules = [_ for _ in zip (rules [::3], rules [2::3] ) ]
names = list (set (name for name, _ in rules) )

def turn ():
    ai = random.choice (names)
    player = input ('Enter your choice: ').lower ()
    if player not in names: raise Exception ('Sheldon out of bounds.')
    print ('AI chose {}.'.format (ai) )
    if (ai, player) in rules:
        print ('AI won.')
        return (0, 1)
    if (player, ai) in rules:
        print ('You won.')
        return (1, 0)
    print ('Draw.')
    return (0, 0)

score = (0, 0)
while True:
    you, ai = turn ()
    score = (score [0] + you, score [1] + ai)
    print ('The score is Human:Machine {}:{}'.format (*score) )
    if input ('Play again? [n/*] ').lower () == 'n': break
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got `outcome` as a global, but you never set it to anything other than "win". So once you've won once, the value of `outcome` will always be "win".

```
def result(player, computer):
    outcome = ""
```

You don't use `outcome` anywhere else, so there's no reason to make it a global anyway.

You really don't even need that variable at all. Combining this with what Hyperboreus' mentioned in his/her answer, your `result` method could start like this, with everything else being the same:

```
def result(player, computer):
    print "Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer])
    global player_score, computer_score
    if computer in rules[player]:
        print "Your victory has been assured."
        ...
```